# How to find out available plugs for a Snap

Tags: snap

Is there a way to find out the available plugs for a particular Snap?

I'd like to run the following command:

```
snap connect pciutils:<plug> :system-observe
```

However, how do I know what to replace "<plug>" with?  Can I run a command to get a list of available plugs for pciutils or pciutils.lspci?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to read up on how Slots and Plugs work and what they specifically mean - see the Snapcraft docs here: https://snapcraft.io/docs/interface-management#heading--slot-plugs

To quote this document, though, it defines a "plug" in line here:

> An interface provides a level of access to resources, such as audio playback, as defined by a *slot*. One or more snaps can access this resource by connecting a corresponding *plug* to the slot.
>
> In other words, the slot is the provider of the resource while the plug is the consumer, and a slot can support multiple plug connections.
>
> [image]

So in your example, you're working with the `system-observe` interface, which has the corresponding **plug** (Snap side) and **slot** (`snapd` daemon side) there.

You can see the available connections a given snap could have with `snap connections SNAPNAME` and it'll list all known plugs and connections for that given snap.

---

Case in point my snap called `rdap` which is a utility to run RDAP queries has two interfaces set to it by the snap, and those are set to auto-connect the `rdap` snap's **plug** side to the `snapd` **slot** side of the interface:

```
$ snap connections rdap
Interface  Plug          Slot      Notes
home       rdap:home     :home     -
network    rdap:network  :network  -
```

(`rdap` only defines the `home` and `network` interface for it which is why only those two are shown)

Comment: Thanks, `snap connections pciutils` worked just great.